# Custom NavigationDrawer with full image as a background

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I can't find solution for implementing very custom NavigationDrawer. I want it to have one image background (black one with white square) with few items like in the picture below:
[image]

Can it be made? As far as I read, it's not really what SDK supports. Only what I got to is that making two items in one line is achievable (still searching for solutions, tho).

Comment: This can be implemented by creating a custom layout for Navigation drawer

Comment: If you use NavigationView, then `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_android"/>`

Comment: Thanks, guys! Done it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BNK answer was the best one:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    android:id="@+id/nav_view" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" 
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"   
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_android"/>
```